# matplotlib window changes size erratically at cursor movement

Tags: python, matplotlib

Using the code below, I get a window that changes size erratically as I hover over it. What am I doing wrong?

(I'm on Ubuntu 18 using Python 3.6 and matplotlib 2.2.2)

[image]

```
fig,axs = plt.subplots(3,1,figsize=(4,6))
#fill each axis with standard ax.plot commands
[ax.set_ylim([-2,2]) for ax in axs]
[ax.text(x=1.1,y=0,s=f"$f_{{{i+1}}}-f_{{{i}}}$") for i,ax in enumerate(axs)]
fig.subplots_adjust(
    left  = 0.1,  # the left side of the subplots of the figure
    right = 0.7  ,  # the right side of the subplots of the figure
    bottom = 0.1 ,  # the bottom of the subplots of the figure
    top = 0.9 ,  # the top of the subplots of the figure
    wspace = 0.9 ,  # the amount of width reserved for blank space between subplots
    hspace = 0.9 ,  # the amount of height reserved for white space between subplots
)
plt.show()
```

Comment: The reason is that the window is too small to host the coordinates next to the toolbar buttons. You may use a larger figure, of course. You may also try with `Qt5Agg` instead of `TkAgg` backend. Or you can disallow for the coordinates to be shown on mouse-over. Which direction would you like to go?

Comment: can I show the toolbar buttons at the top of the window?

Comment: That would be automatically the case with the Qt5Agg backend. If you need/want to keep using tk you would need to [create the GUI yourself](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/user_interfaces/embedding_in_tk_sgskip.html) which would of course also allow you to customize how the coordinates are displayed.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest haha, well, I'll go with Qt5Agg then. thanks.